# Is there a mistake with this national income model Mik. Wisniewski Intro to Math Methods in Econ pg. 61

Tags: finance, economics

I can't figure out the steps to this equation for the national income model.

It seems simple, but I don't see why in step 4 I don't get Y-bY+tY

I thought it was a mistake in the book at first, but that would make the whole model wrong, so is there something I am missing?

```
Y = C+I+G
Y = a+b(Y-tY)+I+G
Y-b(Y-tY)= a+I+G 
Y-bY-btY = a+I+G  (I'm lost here, why isn't it Y-bY+btY?)

Y(1-b-bt) = a+I+G
Y(1-b(1-t)) = a+I+G
Ye = a+I+G / 1-b(1-t)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Indeed a mistake, but in step $6$ another the mistake that 'repairs' it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the book at step 4, and the income equilibrium equation is correct.